# Error with postgres/pdo query binding values

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, pdo

I'm running the following query in postgres:

```
SELECT (SUM(g.grade_days_late) - SUM(s.ex_late_days)) as used_late_days 
FROM grades as g 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM late_day_exceptions ) 
        as s on s.ex_rubric_id = g.rubric_id and s.ex_student_rcs=g.student_rcs 
WHERE g.student_rcs='?' AND g.status=1 AND g.rubric_id < ?
```

with the following commands:

```
$statement = Database::$link->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($parameters);
```

`$parameters` is equal to:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'test' (length=7)
  1 => int 6
```

and I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7 ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2
```

I run the query directly against the database replacing the two ? with the stuff in $parameters and it works fine. If I add ' around the second parameter, the query returns nothing (yet still returns the proper answer if run directly against it with the values inserted).

I really have no idea what's going on here or why I'm getting an error.
(Database is an open PDO connection, no issues there).

Comment: Why do you use a sub select? LEFT JOIN late_day_exceptions should do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `WHERE g.student_rcs= ?` in your query:

```
SELECT (SUM(g.grade_days_late) - SUM(s.ex_late_days)) as used_late_days 
FROM grades as g 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM late_day_exceptions ) 
        as s on s.ex_rubric_id = g.rubric_id and s.ex_student_rcs=g.student_rcs 
WHERE g.student_rcs= ? AND g.status=1 AND g.rubric_id < ?
```

And bind the values like this:

```
$statement = Database::$link->prepare($query);

$statement->bindValue(1, $parameters[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(2, $parameters[1], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$statement->execute();
```

Comment: As soon as I looked at your solution, I realized that '?' was being interpreted as a literal and not as something to be replaced. Ugh, the little things.

Comment: yup, just had to wait for SO to actually let me accept it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The length of the array should match the query output. in your case `used_late_days`

function `execute()` expects a single argument that is an array of parameters. Each element of that array is treated as a query parameter. So right now PDO "thinks" that you pass two parameters while your query contains only one.